# Why does VMWare Player always appear "always on top" of other windows?

Tags: vmware-player, always-on-top

I use VMWare-Player at work.  The virtualization is very useful, but I have one major pet peeve with VMWare.

My workstation has two monitors.  I usually have VMWare running full-screen on one monitor.  Oftentimes, when I click on something on my real (not VMWare) machine (such as to open a new program, for example), a new window opens *behind* the VMWare window.  I must either minimize or move the VMWare window in order to see the window that just opened.

How can I configure my machine so that VMWare will not obscure new windows that open?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the behavior of full-screen apps, unfortunately. It's not VMWare specific. Apps like to open on the primary monitor, which is also where full-screen apps like to be full screened. Short of running VMWare Player in windowed mode, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: I discovered after reading your answer that if I set my VMWare Player to run in a Window and simply make the window take up the whole screen, the problem disappears, but this does not seem like an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using VMWare full screen on your secondary display, but I doubt it is the best way to do it.

I never had any luck running a VM instance in full screen on a single display of my multi monitor setup before, I ended up using Unity function which is a much better solution. However, multi monitor within the VM itself works great, you just need to configure VMWare to use both.

Comment: I've not heard of Unity before.  It sounds like that feature is only in VMWare-Workstation and not VMWare-Player