# VMWare Player: how to avoid always-on-top of other windows

Tags: vmware-player, always-on-top

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/160556/why-does-vmware-player-always-appear-always-on-top-of-other-windows) seems a little bit related, but not fully (I'm not using two monitors nor full-screen mode). I'm running VMWare Player 2.5.4 on Windows XP in **normal window mode**. Unfortunately, if I switch to other applications, VMWare remains the front-most window. I can avoid it by clicking the other application's title bar or if it pops up a dialog, but how can I avoid VMWare's "always-on-top"-mode completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixes with newer versions of VMWare. I'm using version 3.1.3 and it does not stay top-most any more.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the icon in the Windows task bar. Is there a "topmost" or "always on top" option that you can uncheck?

Comment: No, there is no such option.